# SynchronizationLockException after await

Tags: c#, multithreading, windows-8, async-await

I have a method called `HandleMessage`, a new thread is started to handle the message. If the lock object is fetched successfully, then handle it. Otherwise put the message in the queue. A `SynchronizationLockException` is always thrown at `Monitor.Exit(o)` since after `await` the context isn't in the original thread any more. What's the correct way to implement?

```
    public void HandleMessage(string message)
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(async delegate
        {
            if (Monitor.TryEnter(o))
            {
                try
                {
                    do
                    {
                        await HandleMessageAsync(message);
                    }
                    while (queue.TryDequeue(out message));
                }
                finally
                {
                    Monitor.Exit(o);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                queue.Enqueue(message);
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Off-hand, it seems like TPL Dataflow would be a better fit, since your HandleMessage could just Post to the block instead of including this logic?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you've noticed, the Monitor.Enter/Exit are thread-affine.

In their series on creating async-friendly coordination primitives, Stephen includes an [AsyncLock](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/building-async-coordination-primitives-part-6-asynclock/) that should be what you're looking for AFAICT.

Answer (score 1):

Now I found the sync lock `object o` here is useless, because my `queue` is concurrent. At last the solution is:

```
public void HandleMessage(string message)
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew(async delegate
    {
        while (queue.TryDequeue(out message));
        {
           await HandleMessageAsync(message);
        }
    });
}
```

This resolves the problem. But it doesn't answer the question per-se.

Comment: This changes the behavior, though. Before, you could be sure that two messages wouldn't be handled at the same time, but now it is possible. Is that okay in your case?